# How can I increase the amount of memory available to a Corda node?

Tags: corda

We observe the H2 database running out of memory when running a job that issues/modifies more than 6k states sequentially.

How can I provide more memory to the node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide more memory to the node using the `-Xmx` command line flag. For example, if you wanted to run the node with 2gb of heap memory, you would run:

```
java -Xmx2048m -jar corda.jar
```

See more information here: https://docs.corda.net/running-a-node.html#starting-an-individual-corda-node.